# visual studio 2008 error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types (http_parser.h)

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

i try to compile simple c/c++ app that is using http_parser from node.js
i also using libuv , and basically trying to compile [this](https://github.com/philips/libuv-webserver/blob/master/webserver.c) example in windows.
using visual studio 2008

but i getting this compilation error :

```
>d:\dev\cpp\servers\libuv\libuv_http_server\http_parser.h(35) : error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\dev\cpp\servers\libuv\libuv-master\libuv-master\include\uv-private\stdint-msvc2008.h(82) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
```

the code in the http_parser.h file looks like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32__) && (!defined(_MSC_VER) || _MSC_VER<1600)
#include <BaseTsd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
//#undef __int8
typedef __int8 int8_t;
typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t;
typedef __int16 int16_t;
typedef unsigned __int16 uint16_t;
typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
typedef __int64 int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

as you can see i tryed to undef it but it didnt worked.
what can i do so it will pass compilation . 
if i just remove it im getting this error :

```
http_parser.c(180) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'unhex'
```

on this code section :

```
static const int8_t unhex[256] =
  {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  , 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,10,11,12,13,14,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,10,11,12,13,14,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  };
```

and many other sections that using int8_t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's a `typedef`, you can't use `#ifdef` or `#undef` etc, because these only work with symbols that have been `#define`'ed.

The best you can do is to make sure that the two `typedef`'s agree, the there should be no problem.

Looking at `stdint-msvc2008.h`, it might be easier to modify `http_parser.h` to this:

```
typedef signed __int8 int8_t;
```

Any good?

Comment: can you please tell me why adding signd to it solved the problem ?

Comment: @user63898 - I guess because `__int8` can be signed or unsigned and the compiler is being pedantic when comparing the `typedef`'s to insist that the modifiers are the same. Although `signed` is default (according to MSDN) a compiler option can make `unsigned` the default.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1` at the top of your code to avoid redefinition of int8_t.