# File does not exist - dependent error. Issue in building the open source application QCAD

Tags: c++, qt, qcad

I am on Windows 10 - 64 bits.

**Goal:**

I am trying to build this Open Source application [QCAD](http://www.qcad.org/en/) and following there Instructions in [Compiling QCAD from Sources](http://www.qcad.org/en/component/content/article/78-qcad/111-qcad-compilation-from-sources). Following "*Windows*" section, I have done this:

- Installed [MS SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and [.Net framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981)
- Installed [QT Unified Windows x86 2.0.1-1](https://download.qt.io/archive/online_installers/2.0/) with the MSVC2013 and MSVC2015 compilers

**Problem:**

Once I build in QT Creator as MSVC2013->Debug->Mainwindow, I get 8 duplicated errors:

> D:\VisualStudio2015\VC\include\stdint.h:17: error: C2371: 'int8_t':
>   redefinition; different basic types

If I search for `int8_t` I find bunch of its usage and couple of its definitions:

- One in `spatialindex\capi\sidx_config.h`:

  ```
  #if _MSC_VER <= 1500
  typedef __int8 int8_t;
   //..
  typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t;
   //..
  #endif
  ```
- One in `spatialindex\tools\tools.h`

  ```
  #if (defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64 || defined WIN32 || defined WIN64) && !defined __GNUC__ && _MSC_VER!=1800 && _MSC_VER!=1600
  typedef __int8 int8_t;
  //..
  typedef unsigned __int8 uint8_t;
  // ..
  ```

Now if I comment out both statements in the second definition (In `tools.h`) I get some warnings and an error:

> dependent '............\Q-CAD\src\3rdparty\qt-labs-qtscriptgenerator-5.5.0\generated_cpp\com_trolltech_qt_core\qtscript_Global.cpp' does not exist.

**Attempts:**

- If I do what [this guy did](http://www.qcad.org/rsforum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=4002) (He asks about the same error within the post), the dependent error persists.
- I don't want to change any definitions like the answer in [visual studio 2008 error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types (http_parser.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415058/visual-studio-2008-error-c2371-int8-t-redefinition-different-basic-types).

Can you help me accomplish this?

**EDIT**:

"*Now if I comment out both statements in the second definition*" I just commented these couple lines in Tools.h: (No accidents occurred and if I un-comment them I get the previous error).

[image]

Comment: Who did the `#include <stdint.h>`? You or the project? Users should not redefine Standard symbols & should update old projects to remove them. As you can edit the headers, commenting out its redefinitions is probably the best you can do unless/until you get a fixed version. ... **or** maybe this project expects you to compile with pre-C++11 settings to avoid the Standardised `int_t` types. About "if I comment out both statements in the second definition (In tools.h) I get some warning[s] and an error", that doesn't make sense, so probably you accidentally commented out an `#endif` or something

Comment: @underscore_d Not me. I did not do anything in the code except the comment part. And regarding the comment part, see edited please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when I un-checked the "*Shadow Build*" in `Projects Settings` of QT Creator on all: **Debug**, **Profile** and **Release**; and I **ReBuilt All**, It worked like a charm.

It took some time to ReBuild though.

Comment: Short version: QCAD's build configuration is broken.

Comment: I just tried checking back the _Shadow Build_ and ReBuild, it still works. I have no idea what is going on or what went wrong..

Comment: It works because now your source folder is polluted with junk from the previous build. Of course it will work, but if you ever reinstall the source it'll stop working again.

Comment: But should not ReBuild be _cleaning_ junk before Building? and btw, when you first download the source and open it with QT Creator, yes you can "select all" compilers that you have (which I did select all (both) for MSVC 2013 and 15) and configure all files. @KubaOber

Comment: It'll clean junk in your build folder. Which is now a shadow folder, not the source folder.

Comment: To know that it works you must have an absolutely pristine QCAD source folder, and an empty build folder. It'll fail the same way it did before.

Comment: @KubaOber could you please take a look at this http://www.qcad.org/rsforum/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=4358&p=15834#p15834 Maybe you have some ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the [supported platforms](http://www.qcad.org/en/qcad-documentation/supported-platforms), it only mentions msvc2010 and msvc2013; you are trying to build using msvc2015 which is not supported. Try to change the compiler and see if it works.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to mention that I get the same error on both buildings `MSVC2013` and `MSVC2015`. I installed it just for QT Creator to configure it and for me to be able to upgrade easily later. But I am using MSVC2013 to build.

Comment: @FirstStep You did build your Qt using MSVC2013 too, right?

Comment: @KubaOber Correct. When I started the project, I configured as both MSVC2013 and MSVC2015 (select all)

Comment: If you built your own Qt, then there's no such thing as "select all". You'll have one installation/build of Qt for each compiler version.

Comment: @KubaOber see my answer. I do **not** know why it did "_not work_" first, now I do **not** know why "_it works_" :D